# Swapping Widgets / Replacing Layouts in Kivy With on_touch_down()

Tags: python, kivy

Okay, so I've got a program that, under certain conditions, needs to remove some options and present some other ones. I originally designed it so that certain buttons would occupy the same space. However, when the `on_touch_down()` is triggered, the intended switch I've coded doesn't swap layouts.

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy import graphics
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from SpotChess import SCBoardWidget
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout

promote_now = False

class Chessboard(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Chessboard, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(pos=self.drawBoardandPieces)
        self.bind(size=self.drawBoardandPieces)
        self.drawBoardandPieces()

    def drawBoardandPieces(self, *args):
        with self.canvas:
            # Reset the canvas in case of redraws.
            self.canvas.clear()
            # Define the lengths of the edges of the squares.
            edge_len = min(self.height, self.width) // 8
            Config.set("graphics", "resizable", True)
            for column in range(0, 8):
                for row in range(0, 8):
                    if ((row + column) % 2) == 0:
                        graphics.Color(0, 0, 1)
                        self.dark_rect = graphics.Rectangle(pos=(column*edge_len, row*edge_len),
                                                            size=(edge_len, edge_len))
                    else:
                        graphics.Color(1, 1, 1)
                        self.light_rect = graphics.Rectangle(pos=(column*edge_len, row*edge_len),
                                                             size=(edge_len, edge_len))

    # This provides all of the user's mouse interaction with the board.
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        global promote_now
        if promote_now == False:
            promote_now = True
            Options().swapMenus()
        else:
            promote_now = False
            Options().swapMenus()

game_board = Chessboard()

class PromotionOptions(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PromotionOptions, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 4

        self.queen_btn = Button(text="Q/q")
        self.rook_btn = Button(text="R/r")
        self.bishop_btn = Button(text="B/b")
        self.knight_btn = Button(text="N/n")

        self.add_widget(self.queen_btn)
        self.add_widget(self.rook_btn)
        self.add_widget(self.bishop_btn)
        self.add_widget(self.knight_btn)

class Options(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Options, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.swapMenus()

    def swapMenus(self):
        global promote_now
        self.clear_widgets()
        if promote_now == False:
            # Present the menu layout for normal play.
            self.normal_play_menu = GridLayout(cols=3)
            # It contains the button to flip the board.
            self.flip_board_btn = Button(text="Flip")
            self.normal_play_menu.add_widget(self.flip_board_btn)
            self.add_widget(self.normal_play_menu)
        else:
            # Present the menu layout for pawn promotions.
            self.promotion_menu = GridLayout(cols=1)
            self.promotion_menu.add_widget(widget=PromotionOptions())
            self.add_widget(self.promotion_menu)

class SCApp(App):
    def build(self):
        top_portion = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        chessboard_portion = RelativeLayout()
        chessboard_portion.add_widget(widget=game_board)
        top_portion.add_widget(widget=chessboard_portion)
        bottom_portion = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        bottom_portion.add_widget(widget=Options())
        app_layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        app_layout.add_widget(top_portion)
        app_layout.add_widget(bottom_portion)
        return app_layout

SCApp().run()
```

I'm clearly calling the object to perform the replacement, but it's not completing either the `self.clear_widgets()` or the `self.add_widget()`, even though I've called the function. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `on_touch_down()` method the

```
Options().swapMenus()
```

lines are creating new instances of the `Options` class, and calling the `swapMenus()` method of that new instance. But that new instance of `Options` is not in your GUI, so it haas no effecet on your App. You need to get a reference to the `Options` instance that IS in your GUI, and call the `swapMenus()` method of that instance.

You can do that by saving a reference to the `Options` class in your `App`, by replacing this line in your `build()` method:

```
    bottom_portion.add_widget(widget=Options())
```

with:

```
    self.options = Options()
    bottom_portion.add_widget(widget=self.options)
```

Then in the `on_touch_down()` method:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    global promote_now
    
    # get the instance of Options that is in the App
    options = App.get_running_app().options
    
    if promote_now == False:
        promote_now = True
        options.swapMenus()
    else:
        promote_now = False
        options.swapMenus()
```

Comment: This is what I ended up figuring out, too. I resolved that problem by creating a global `options` variable that is just a copy of that class. Does the `App.get_running_app().widget_name` save on computing time, by chance?

Comment: No, the global variable is probably faster.